# Akka remote actors filter connections by IP

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-remote-actor

I'm trying to add security to my remote actors. I've set untrusted-mode:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html

Is it possible to add IP filtering, to allow connection only from specific server? For example I have one master and 10 slaves, I want to allow only for my master (specific IP) to connect my slaves.

In open source everyone could just create a new instance of my master, and connect to my real slaves. How can make it secure?

Comment: Did you check akka-cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Using IP filtering is not very secure as it's easy to fake an IP. Luckily Akka comes with secure transport support via SSL and secure cookie support.

A cookie is like an API key and will be required to establish the connection. SSL will guarantee eavesdropping is not possible to steal the secure cookie. See this [doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0-RC2/scala/remoting.html#SSL) for example.

I made a simple project that uses Akka remoting and SSL with secure cookie. Try it out [here](https://github.com/izmailoff/remote-akka-server-template). Read how to setup SSL certificate storage and such [here](https://github.com/izmailoff/remote-akka-server-template/blob/master/SECURITY.md).